# jsoup select elements

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to scrape a website for data using jsoup. But having some problems with getting some text.

Part of the html looks like this

```
<p class="time">9:00</p>
```

which i can grab fine using the line of code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
doc.select("p.time").text());
```

but the next bit of html looks like this:

```
<p class="date"><strong>FRIDAY 27<sup>th</sup></strong> JULY 2012</p>
```

Which i'm not sure how to get. Using the line:

```
doc.select("p.date").text());
```

just gets me an empty string. I've tried variations of that (i.e. selecting "p.date" and then try date.select("strong")) but just keep coming up with a empty strings.

how do I go about getting that date text?

Comment: how about `doc.select("p.date").child(0).text();` for example ? or `doc.select("p.date strong").text();`

Answer (score 1):

Unable to reproduce your problem.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<html><body><p class=\"date\"><strong>FRIDAY 27<sup>th</sup></strong> JULY 2012</p></body></html>");
String s = doc.select("p.date").text();
System.out.println(s);
```

This prints: "FRIDAY 27th JULY 2012"